# JavaScript / HTML image transition effect

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to emulate the "heart" transition shown at:

http://www.templatemonster.com/flash-templates/31595.html?scr_type=1&hide_flash=0&tab=32

in HTML5 / JS, but I don't really know where to start. Any tips? JQuery-based stuff is fine by me.

Comment: There's about 50 different hearts in that animation. Which particular transition are you asking about?

Comment: The intro one or the PhotoAlbum? I agree with DA there are lots of hearts

Comment: The "main" heart. The rest of the hearts are just pink/purple/whatever, but the central heart is a "window" through which you see the next picture. It then grows until it fills the entire box, at which point the new picture is visible / old one is obscured.

Comment: Which browsers do you have to support? Webkit can do image masks, but is limited to Webkit, of course: http://css-tricks.com/8151-webkit-image-wipes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas clip mask is a good starting point
https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_2_canvas_clipping.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fabulant.com/downloadcenter/imgtransheart/imgtransheart.html

Script is v. easy to follow and modify. You can use your own heart images (the covering images are loaded in the js). Only trick is making sure the transparent aperture is smoothly scaled for each image.

Comment: Seems like a pretty poor way of doing it, rather than scaling an image. This will result in much smoother animation than the linked article.